# authenticate and login user with GET request

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've got a task of logging in user in GET request with specified login and password as arguments in url string. I've done it like this:

```
def login_view(request):
    username = request.GET.get('login')
    password = request.GET.get('passwd')
    print('Is authenticated', request.user.is_authenticated)
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        print('Is authenticated', request.user.is_authenticated)
        return redirect('home')
    return HttpResponse("Login failed")
```

and it must be working as it seemingly complies with documentation except the request method. In documentation it's POST but i've to make it for GET.

So now it's not authenticated:

```
Is authenticated False
Is authenticated False
```

and I'm sure it's due to wrong method type. Do you have any suggestions on how to work around this issue?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to use GET for logging, see [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147188/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-get-method-as-login-username-password-for-administrato).

Comment: It's for internal usage as well as GET request is made by existing program, which is out of my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like i've messed up in imports, i've imported

`from django.contrib.auth.views import login`

instead of

`from django.contrib.auth import login`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to print username and password? Are they passing correctly?

Instead of this

```
 print('Is authenticated', request.user.is_authenticated)
```

Print this

```
print('Is authenticated', user.is_authenticated)
```

Comment: Yes, it says user is authenticated.

Comment: It works for user object but not for the one stored in request. At home view i've a check `print(self.request.user)` which says AnonymousUser. as well as in template i've got logic like `% if user.is_authenticated %}`.

Comment: You can do like this `request.user = user` and save it like `request.user.save()`

Comment: it's not working. And i'm sure the user must be set inside django's login method.